# How to fix one letter typos?

Tags: support, edits

I found some questions and answers where one of the relevant words 
contains a typo. (In my case the user wrote 'QlickView' instead of 'Qlikview'.)

I would like to change (edit) these questions and answers, so that the search finds them. But it is not possible to save one letter changes.

Should I flag these questions and answers or is there a better way to improve?

Comment: get_all_posts | sed -e 's/Qlickview/Qlikview/' | save_all_posts ... easy peasy

Comment: Don't focus on that single word. Focus on the post as a whole. More often than not you'll find more to fix than the single character.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the 'QlickView's, there is only one left in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586814/microsoft-business-intelligence-platform-vs-qlikview ;-) Great job.

Comment: @smartmeta [14 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10586814/revisions). Focus on the full post, not the single typo.

Comment: Related on [Meta.AU](http://meta.askubuntu.com/): [How to make small but important edits?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3906/how-to-make-small-but-important-edits), [Is it acceptable to make small edits?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3946/is-it-acceptable-to-make-small-edits)

Comment: You are forced to make some useful but less relevant changes at the same time. Fixing whitespace is an example. In non-code posts, you can almost always find a word which can be replaced with a better equivalent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't. Leave those to people with 2k+ rep.

The suggested edit system is intended for substantial edits only. If you cannot find more things to fix, leave the typo be.

Comment: Ha, you are the FGITW. That would be an irony on the post talking about typos.

Comment: Doesn't that sort of go against the spirit of SO? Even Wikipedia will let you make one letter changes with no issues.

Comment: @0A0D: Suggested edits go through a review queue, it'd be a waste of everyones time to allow 1-character suggested edits. That's why there is a minimum character requirement, and you are expected to make *substantial* edits only. Reach 2k and you can make all the small edits you want.

Comment: I suppose. I am a 13.9k user so I surpassed that requirement long ago, I just have a differing opinion. To me any edits make the site better.

Comment: @0A0D: But you need to have gained enough trust first. Before that point, edits are subject to review. Spammers would *love* the opportunity to make edits willy nilly everywhere. :-)

Comment: Yes, I thought of that after I posted my last comment. I suppose we need to be a little more guarded than Wikipedia

Comment: And what if the one letter typo is a very misleading typo that matters? flag it?

Comment: @iight: I don't think flag should be used for that purpose. Probably ask someone in chat room with edit privilege to fix it.

Comment: @iight: Usually a comment would do just fine.

Comment: cool aright ... i hate when that happens hahah