# It's been more than 10 days, Am I permanently banned for suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, edit-ban

To [reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days) this question I understood that I'm having too many edits rejected.

Everyday, whenever I'm trying to edit a post it gives me error

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review [your
>   edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3259815/vaibhav-mule?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

I search a lot come to know it shows days like you can edits posts after 5 days or something. I'm not getting anything.

Am I permanently banned from suggesting edits?
and It's been more than 10 days I have got banned so can you please tell when I will get access to edits?

Comment: You were manually banned for 30 days because a moderator determined that you were making "a very large number of edits that add little or no value to the posts you're editing" (quoted).

Comment: @animuson can you tell how can i check on which day bann will remove?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems your ban was substantial given the number of rejected edits you were getting.

### Edits need to be useful/worthwhile

On 20th April, you had:
*Rejected 12*
*Accepted 17*

That's not really a very good balance.
So I would also suggest as a friendly note, you should really look over your rejections and try to learn why you are being rejected so much.

It's welcomed that people help out, in fact it's one of the core principles the sites are built upon - community moderating.
But the *help* has to be useful and worthwhile.

Every rejected edit you get is reviewed by a bunch of users, and stored in databases, looked over by moderators and users with high rep in stats, etc.

So, please try to make them useful edits.

**For example:**

This edit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7751687

Is a tiny edit and very arguably "trivial".
In fact, it isn't actually "necessary" and the post is perfectly fine without it.

---

Have a read of these posts, they might help:)

[Editing Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
> change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

[A blog post by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/):

> If you are going to edit a post, make sure you’re substantively
> improving it. Avoid making isolated, trivial edits, as they are the
> source of much friction. For example, don’t bother changing "its" to
> "it’s" unless you have several other edits to make in the same post.

Some other questions/answers:

[Why are trivial edits discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74430/why-are-trivial-edits-discouraged)

[Why is editing so hard?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214884/why-is-editing-so-hard)

Comment: Thanks lesson learned.

Comment: Not disagreeing with the conclusion here at all, but to be totally fair to the OP: The second edit you use as an example also added a tag that seems valid. Still not a lot to it, but at least there was *something* positive about the edit.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I did not see that, and in fact further inspection shows two reviewers had *approved* and was only rejected because of edit clash. Thanks for pointing it out, have edited as my point was an unfair and inaccurate.

Comment: @James I don't know as stackechange is community driven software, may be we have to accept even it is unfair and inaccurate.