# Show how many edits I already suggested and if it's over the limit

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I think there should be a markdown counting of suggestion limit, like
how many I applied and how many I've left. Or is it already there and
I didn't get it yet?

Comment: What do you mean by *"But it is solving all my question and also it is in scattered that need to find the all answers."*? It is incomprehensible. Can you fix it (preferably by editing your question)?

Comment: The accepted answer to the dupe target has all you need to know about the rate limit, expressed very concisely.

Comment: @NathanTuggy what about my query given in block-quote.

Comment: Actually, if the number of suggested edits has gone over the limit you'll already know, because won't the system automatically reject your suggested edit?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to currently do this is to go to your profile:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

and count how many pending edits you have:

[image]

<sub>before you ask: this is indeed a screenshot made today</sub>

Subtract this number from 5 (20 if you're on a beta site), and you have your desired result. Beta sites can be recognized by the word 'Beta' next to their name in the title under the navigation bar (though there are a few exceptions).

Comment: From there I can only count one by one only the pending counts, but how can I get remaining counts.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to suggest several edits in a brief space of time.

Let's say you edit 15 posts within 15 minutes, automatically your edits enter the review system where two (or three) users have to approve each one.

Well, if someone sees the same user's name popping up, and if the edits do nothing to improve those posts they might start rejecting the other edits. The opposite is true if the edits are pertinent, useful, suggest significant changes without being invasive, and generally help improve the legibility. When that happens, users will trust your suggestions and  approve them more quickly.

Shog9 ♦'s answer to the question [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits)  might be of interest

[emphasis mine]

> As of a few seconds ago, [Jul 13 '16] this limit is now active network-wide:
>
> **at-most 20** pending suggested **edits per editor** on **beta** sites
> **at-most 5** pending suggested edits per editor on **graduated** sites
> These limits are based on my analysis of the speed at which edits are generally approved and the number of edits (and editors) that would have been affected over the past few months.

See also this question [Moderators should be able to manually ban users from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)

and this [It's been more than 10 days, Am I permanently banned for suggesting edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254611/its-been-more-than-10-days-am-i-permanently-banned-for-suggesting-edits)

I believe six or more rejected edits in a row triggers an *automatic* ban from suggesting further edits by the system. P.S. I looked for what that specific number was but didn't find one. In any case, you'll want to know *before* your account is banned whether an edit of yours has been rejected. Read the reason/s why it was rejected and try not to make the same mistake.

To read the reasons visit **Profile**, click on **Activity**, then go to the ***responses*** tab. Select ***suggestions*** where you'll see which edits were approved and which were rejected.

To summarise, take it slow because low-quality, trivial, well-meaning but ungrammatical edits will always be rejected in the review queue.

A much faster way to gain rep is to answer a question.

Comment: You get banned from suggesting edits if, in the last seven days, [five more than 1/3 of your approved edits in the same timeframe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337) are rejected. (Automatic rejections due to edit conflicts are neither approved nor rejected when doing this calculation.)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it can be useful indeed.

I suggest the following mockup:

> [image]

i.e. show the amount you suggested and the limit besides the edit link itself, in brackets. When the amount suggested reach the limit, have it red and unclickable.

Comment: You changed the original title into a clear feature request. I didn't interpret it that way.

Comment: The  title [edited but approved by the OP] was: *How can I see how many pending edit suggestions I have and how many more I can make?*

Comment: @Mari-LouA it was already a clear feature request in the body, the title did not match hence I fixed it. If not a feature request, it's duplicate, and it really was, I closed it as such. (By reopening, other users made it a feature request)

Comment: I don't see any link that answers the OP's request. [*“The accepted answer to the dupe target”*] Might have been an idea to have left a link showing why the OP's post was considered a duplicate. The edited title was there for a good four hours. See Glorfindel's answer, *posted only an hour ago*, his answer provides a link to the suggested edits. My answer explains why the user should not  post a series of edits in one go.